# Why are σ algebras defined with countable intersections and not uncountable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, set-theory

I am trying to understand the motivation for defining sigma algebras with countable intersections/unions.

From what I gathered:
If Ω, a non-empty subset, is finite, every possible subset of Ω is measurable and finite intersections do everything that infinite intersections would.

However, there are cases where we might want to consider infinite Ω, both countable and uncountable.

For example, considering the number of coin flips until TAILS appears for the first time, Ω is the set of Natural numbers.

And when considering intervals in the real numbers, Ω is uncountably infinite.

I read some lecture notes saying that closure under uncountable intersections applied to Vitali sets make everything measure 0 or +inf (making measure theory unable to measure anything) and that because of this, sigma fields are defined only with closure under countable intersections.

I also found a lecture that said that Vitali sets break measure theory even under countable intersections, and so it's necessary to restrict the set of things that are measurable.

Could someone shed some light on this? Do Vitali sets need uncountable infinity to break measure theory? Are uncountable intersections not stronger than countable?

The intuition that I have in my head is that: uncountable infinity is so infinite that 'measures' lose their meaning. But it feels a bit wonky.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is about the use of $\sigma$-algebras in measure theory. You want to avoid trying to measure unmeasurable sets (which may for example be an uncountable union of sets each of which is measurable).  You also want to try to avoid summing an uncountable number of $0$s and getting a positive result. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420386/why-countable-unions-intersections-etc and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145981/why-can-t-measures-be-defined-on-uncountable-powersets-example-that-actually-ap are also related

Comment: These posts are great, thank you so much. I understand now why uncountable intersections aren't used. And if I understood correctly, things like Vitali sets are the motivation to define some subsets as not measurable, even when dealing with countable intersections? PS: I went through a lot of stack exchange posts and did not find the one you linked Ethan... I'm getting rusty. Thanks again.

Comment: @jxx that is true to some extent, but the Vitali set only shows that a countably additive generalization of the notion of length is impossible on a power set of $\mathbb R$. It shows that there is a price to pay if one wants such an object, but it does not actually tell the full story of why one is then interested in making the domain of a measure a $\sigma$ algebra

Comment: Could you point me somewhere where i can learn why the domain of a measure is made into a sigma algebra? I had the idea that the sigma algebra was created by defining these properties that we wish to have (countable additivity, closed under comprement, omega included) and putting them into their own structure (because using the whole power set does not allow for all these properties)

Comment: The answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/why-do-we-need-sigma-algebras-to-define-probability-spaces states that sigma algebras are only required when dealing with uncountable Omega, otherwise anything in the powerset of Omega is measureable. Is this right? Ah, Vitali sets are countably additive but Omega is still uncountable.